# How to check multiple workflows are successful or not in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two repos that trigger GitHub workflows. For example, I have 2 parallel workflows in each repo, repoA (test, build) and repoB (test, build). Once all 4 workflows are successful I want to send one notification to Slack. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If they're separate repos, there's no guarantee that they'll both be pushed to to trigger builds at the same time. Or to look at it another way: if they _are_ always pushed to at the same time, should they really be separate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In repoA I have two workflows test, build and repoB has test, build workflows. when I trigger repoA it will trigger test, build and repoB's test and build workflows. All of them run parallelly. I want to know if all all 4 of them ran successfully or not. If 4 of them ran successfully I need to send a notification.

Comment: @lakshmiravali rimmalapudi did you ever find a solution?